# Can't find all tables in website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the code for all the tables inside http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1932, but I'm only getting the first table.

I've tried switching the parser to lxml, but it still gives the length value of 1 for total tables.

It also doesn't give the all of the tags such as divs, tds ...etc

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = 'http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1932'

url = base_url

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

print len(soup.find_all('table'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your page render the table by javascript.
So there is 2 ways to do that

- first one is using a scraping engine with javascript like Selenium.
- second one is finding inside the html content and render it yourself.

For this code I approach the 2nd one. Found that the table was hidden by `<--` and `-->`.
Just find all those things and replace it.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = 'http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1932/'

url = base_url

r = requests.get(url)
content = re.sub(r'(?m)^\<!--.*\n?', '', r.content)
content = re.sub(r'(?m)^\-->.*\n?', '', content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
print len(soup.find_all('table'))
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    if table.findParent("table") is None:
        print "\n\n", str(table)
```